# How to calculate time difference between two cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I've time value in two columns in my sheet. Ex: Col A & B
In col C i want the time difference between time in A & B

Example :
[image]

But it is giving me seconds difference.
I've tried the formula `=INT((B2-A2)*24)` but i got hours alone.

My expected result is how many hours,min,seconds differed`01:20:52` in two cells.

How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cell formula as `=b2-a2` (ie. the smaller should be subtracted from the larger, not vice versa) and format the cell as `Time` or `[h]:mm:ss`